# Datetime in C# - why doesn't milliseconds show and get subsequently stored in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Why doesn't milliseconds show in the `datetime` and get subsequently stored in SQL Server?

It shows as 11/14/2017 3:46:14 PM. The milliseconds are there - 323 but not part of the `datetime`.

So I want it stored in the SQL Server table as 11/14/2017 3:46:14.323 PM.

However, it stores it as 11/14/2017 3:46:14 PM.

The table column is `dateTime`.

Here's a debug shot of the date in the C# code.

[image]

Here's the table;

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's storing it, it's just not displaying it back to you in *that grid*.  See the SQL Server documentation on [datetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql) for info:  "Accuracy: Rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds"

Comment: If this is a new schema I would recommend that you use `datetime2` over `datetime`. You can specify the precision so it is more accurate and `datetime` will eventually be deprecated (*although it is not clear when and there is no definitive point in time that I can find*).

Comment: You can see the milliseconds despite the format in the management studio by executing: select datepart(millisecond, LogDateTime)

Comment: The SSMS GUI is merely hiding MSec from you, it's stored and queryable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a display format problem.You can use this code in SSMS:

```
SELECT CAST ('11/14/2017 3:46:14.323 PM' AS DATETIME)
```

You will see millseconds. In fact,the data stored is the same.